# Dijkstra's algorithm for computing the GCD of two integers, translated from C to x86 assembly

Tags: algorithm, c, assembly

This is the x86 version of a C file assignment (I have included both). We were to convert the C code to assembly. I am rather new at assembly and would really appreciate suggestions and help for optimization and functionality.

This is a C implementation of Dijkstra's recursive algorithm for computing the greatest common divisor of two integers.

```
#include <unistd.h>         
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define STDIN   0
#define STDOUT  1

unsigned int getInt(char* string) {

    unsigned int result = 0;
    char* digit = string;
    while (*digit != '\n') digit++; // Obtain the address of
    digit--;                        // the last digit character
    while (digit >= string) {
        if (*digit == ' ') break;
        if (*digit < '0' || *digit > '9') {
            char* errorMessage = "Bad Number.\n";
            write(STDOUT,errorMessage,12);
            exit(0);
        }
        // use the MUL (dword) instruction here (unsigned multiply)
        // be careful to understand its operands and results
        result += (*digit - '0') * digitValue;
        digitValue *= 10;
        digit--;                    // walk backwards from least
    }                               // significant to most
    return result;
}
void makeDecimal(unsigned int n) {
    // use the DIV (dword) instruction here (unsigned divide)
    // be careful to understand its operands and results
    unsigned int remainder = n % 10;
    unsigned int  quotient = n / 10;
    if (quotient > 0) makeDecimal(quotient);  // notice recursion!
    char digit = remainder + '0';
    write(STDOUT,&digit,1);
}


int readNumber() {
    char data[20];
    char* prompt = "Enter a positive integer: ";
    write(STDOUT,prompt,26);
    read(STDIN,data,20);
    return getInt(data);
}

unsigned int gcd(unsigned int n, unsigned int m) {
    if (n > m) {
        return gcd(n - m, m);   // recursion
    } else if (n < m) {
        return gcd(n, m - n);   // recursion
    } else return n;            // base case
}

int main() {
    char newLineChar = '\n';
    unsigned int a, b, answer;
    a = readNumber();
    b = readNumber();
    answer = gcd(a,b);
    char* message = "Greatest common divisor = ";
    write(STDOUT,message,26);
    makeDecimal(answer);
    write(STDOUT,&newLineChar,1);
    exit(0);
}
```

This is the assembly version of the C program. The task is to implement this same program entirely in 32-bit x86 assembly language (for assembly by NASM and execution under Linux).

```
SECTION .data
posInt:    db       'First num',10
posIntL    equ       $-posInt
badNum:     db      'Bad Number.',10
badNumL     equ     $-badNumL
gcdiv:      db      'GCD = ',10 ; greatest common divisor
gcdL        equ     $-gcdL
answ:       db      " ",10
answL       equ     $-answ
testP:      db  'It got here: ',10
testLen     equ $-testP
lVal:       equ 48
hVal:       equ 57

SECTION .bss
result:     resb    8
chars:      equ 20
inbuf1:     resb    chars + 1   ;space for 22 bytes

SECTION .text
global gcd
global makeDec
global getInt
global numRead
global main



main:
    call    numRead
    mov     ebx, eax        
    call    numRead         
    mov     ecx, eax        
    push    ebx             
    push    ecx             
    call    gcd             
    mov     esi, eax        
    push    esi
    call    makeDec
    mov     eax, 1          
    mov     ebx, 0
    int 80H

numRead:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp    
    push    ebx
    push    ecx
    push    edx

    nop
    mov     eax, 4              
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, posInt
    mov     edx, posIntL
    int 80H

    mov     eax, 3
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     ecx, inbuf1
    mov     edx, chars
    int 80H

    push    inbuf1
    call    getInt
    add     esp, 4

    pop     edx
    pop     ecx
    pop     ebx
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret

getInt:

    push     ebp
    mov      ebp, esp
    push     ebx        
    push     ecx       
    push     edx        
    push     edi        

    mov     edi, [ebp+8]
    mov     ecx, edi

    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 0

findLast:
    mov     dl, [ecx]
    cmp     dl, 10
    jne     increment
    dec     ecx
    jmp     validOrBad

increment:
    inc ecx         
    jmp     findLast

validOrBad:
    cmp     ecx, edi
    jb      getIntReturn 

    mov     dl, [ecx]
    cmp     dl, 32
    je      getIntReturn

    cmp     dl, lowVal      
    jl      badNumber

    cmp     dl, highVal
    jg      badNumber

validNum:

    sub     dl, 48
    imul    dx, bx

    add     al, dl

    imul    bx, 10
    dec     ecx
    jmp     validOrBad

badNumber: 

    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, badNum
    mov     edx, badNumL
    int     80H

    mov     eax, 1
    mov     ebx, 0
    int 80H

getIntReturn:
    pop     edi
    pop     edx
    pop     ecx
    pop     ebx
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret

makeDecimal:

    nop
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    ebx
    push    ecx
    push    edx

    mov     ebx, 10 
    xor     edx, edx
    div     ebx
    cmp     eax, 0
    jle     notEqual

makeDecimalRECURSION:

    push    eax
    call    makeDecimal
    add     esp, 8

notEqual:

    add     edx, lowVal
    mov     [result], dl

    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, gcdiv
    mov     edx, gcdL
    int 80H

    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, result
    mov     edx, 1
    int 80H

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, answerSpace
    mov edx, spaceLen
    int 80H

    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

gcd:

    nop
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    ebx
    push    ecx

    mov     ebx, [ebp+8]    ;var n
    mov     ecx, [ebp+12]   ;var m

    cmp     ebx, ecx
    jl      LESS
    jg      GREATER
    je      FINISH


LESS:

    sub     ecx, ebx    
    push    ebx
    push    ecx
    call    gcd

    pop     ebx
    pop     ecx
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret

GREATER:

    sub     ebx, ecx
    push    ebx
    push    ecx
    call    gcd

    pop     ecx
    pop     ebx
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret

FINISH:

    mov     eax, ebx
    pop     ecx
    pop     ebx
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Note that this NASM code doesn't build correctly: [Why do I get an error in NASM when running this StackExchange codereview program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67309583) on SO has the fixes to get it to build.

Comment: Related SO canonical answers: [ASCII decimal -> integer input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057) with simpler non-digit detection, avoiding imul, and not using weird 16-bit operand-size for no apparent reason.  [Integer -> ASCII decimal output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894): non-recursive, correctly prints all the digits, unlike yours which seems to use a fixed EDX=1 length for outputting the `result` digit-string?  And has 3 different `write` system calls, including one from an `answerSpace` buffer which isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My thoughts (in no particular order):

1. Short on comments.  Assembler in particular benefits from comments.
2. Uses a very conservative style (params passed on stack, all regs preserved, maintain stack frames). For max performance (often the reason to use asm vs high level languages), there are alternatives (pass params in regs, omit stack frame, assume certain regs clobbered during 'call') that use less memory and give better performance.
3. Maybe omit `jl LESS`, since that's the default.
4. What's with `nop`?

---

Edit: I'm expanding on #2 since it was so terse.

I'm probably harping on this too much, but I think it's an important point to understand about asm programming.

There are rules when programming a computer.  Some are enforced by the CPU (mustn't divide by 0, no NULL references, etc).  Some are defined by the assembler (accidentally typing `mvo eax, 0` instead of `mov eax, 0`).

And some are defined by the high level languages (like C).  If one routine written in C is going to call another routine written in C, they must agree on a set of rules.  Where is the calling routine going to put the parameters so that the called routine can find them?  What registers must the called routine preserve?  All?  Some?  None?  Where is the return value from the called routine going to be?

But whatever decisions C made are just that: Decisions made by the people who designed the C language.  Fortran might use different rules.  Pascal, java, COBOL might all do something different.

But asm, ahh...

If your asm code was going to call a C function (yes, that can be done), then you would have to follow the C rules about where to put the parameters and where the C routine will return its result.  But when one asm routine calls another, it can use any of the high level language rules (making it flexible enough to work with any language), or use none of them and make up its own.

Which brings us back to your question about removing the stack as a way to pass parameters.  The code below doesn't really follow any industry standard rules.  But 'main' and 'gcd' are both written according to the same rules.  And since they agree, the code works as intended.  And the resulting code is (a bit) more efficient.

(I'm going to base this on JS1's code, but you can see where this happens in yours)

Let's start with the existing code.  You read values from the stack:

```
mov     eax, [ebp+8]    ;var n
mov     edx, [ebp+12]   ;var m
```

But *why* do you read it from the stack?  Well, the reason you read it from the stack is that when you call the function, that's where you put the values:

```
push    eax
push    edx
call    gcd
```

But why do you push the values before you call the function?  Well, you do it because that's where the function is going to read them.  In other words, we do it because we need to, and we need to because we do it.  It's just a decision you have made about how you will pass the parameters.

So what's the alternative?

What if you just change the rule so that instead of pushing the parameters before you made the call, you just always made sure that eax and edx contain the values you want before you make the call?  Then, instead of loading eax and edx from the stack, they are already there.

It's easy to forget and think of registers like variables that go out of scope when you call a function.  But that's not how registers work.  There is only 1 edx.

I haven't run this (I'm not on Linux), but how about something like this:

```
gcd:
    cmp     eax, edx
    jg      GREATER
    je      FINISH

    sub     edx, eax ; LESS case
    jmp     RECURSE
GREATER:
    sub     eax, edx
RECURSE:
    call    gcd      ; args popped off by FINISH

FINISH:              ; return value must be in eax
    ret
```

Since we are passing the parameters in registers, the push statements before the call to gcd are no longer needed.  And since we aren't following cdecl anymore, I also got rid of the stack frame stuff (the ebp stuff).

So what happens: We assume that eax and edx are set before the routine starts (more on that below).  We compare them, subtract as necessary and (possibly) call gcd again.  And if the rule is that we must have the values in eax and edx before we call gcd, why, they're already there!

So, we do a lot less pushing/popping, have fewer instructions, use less memory, I'm pretty sure this is even gluten free.

(Q: As a thought exercise: what happens if you change the "call gcd" by RECURSE to "jmp gcd"?  See answer below.)

We still need to change the code in main that calls gcd for the first time.  It needs to make sure the parameters are where the new rule says they are:

```
call    numRead
mov     edx, eax        
call    numRead
; value is already in eax
call    gcd
```

And here is why having rules is so important.

I'm moving the return value from the first numRead call into edx.  Then I call numRead again.  If numRead treated edx as volatile (the way gcd does), my first number would get overwritten during the second call to numRead (there is only 1 edx register no matter where you are in the program).

And that's part of why I think comments in asm are so important.  Having a comment block at the top of each function that describes the purpose of the function, lists what the inputs are (and where they are), and what gets preserved and what gets clobbered can save you a lot of grief.

That's also the benefit of following common standards.  If all your asm follows one industry-standard convention (cdecl, stdcall, fastcall, x64, etc), then you don't even have to read the comments to know what the rules for that function are.  It may not always be as efficient, but if your project has a lot of code, it is much easier to maintain.

In this case since I know that numRead preserves edx, I take advantage of that fact to keep things simple in main.

Hope this clears up what I was talking about.

(A: Your teacher probably gives you a failing grade, because the code is no longer recursive.  But it runs even faster, and uses even less memory).

Comment: Can that be done while maintaining the recursion element?

Comment: Yes.  Most of this is covered by JS1's answer under 'volatile registers.'

Comment: I did actually omit the nop and jl LESS from the code. I tried researching online to see how to do recursion without the stack element but alas to no avail. Could you provide an example and/or explanation on how this would work.

Comment: That was a fantastic explanation and clears a lot up! My purpose was not entirely based on a course grade but practicality and functionality while processing as optimal as possible. and your explanation takes care of most of those aspirations if not all. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.  Like JS1, I assumed recursion was an assignment requirement.  JS1 is quite correct that recursion is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Related: (non-recursive) [Greatest Common Divisor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77334) (on codegolf.SE, but that version is basically "normal", not golfed heavily).  `div` instead of repeated-`sub` is still basically the same algorithm, but using div as a shortcut for each sequence of the same subs.

Answer (score 5):

#### Missing stack fixup

In `main()`, you push arguments to `gcd()` and `makeDec()` but don't pop them or add back to the stack pointer.  If you actually returned from `main`, your program would crash.

#### Use volatile registers, not preserved ones

First, I'm assuming you are following the cdecl calling convention and the Intel ABI.  Under the Intel ABI, the registers `eax`, `ecx`, and `edx` are volatile registers, which means that a function can trash their values and not preserve them.  Registers such as `ebx` and `esi` are preserved registers, which means a function must preserve their value.

In `gcd()`, you have chosen to use `ebx` and `ecx`, and have attempted to preserve them (I think).

1. In both the `LESS` case and the `GREATER` case, you restore the stack by `mov esp, ebp`, which means that you failed to restore the `ebx` value that you pushed at the very top of the function.
2. If you used `eax` or `edx` instead of `ebx`, you could delete the two pushes at the beginning and the two pops in the `FINISH` case, because you wouldn't need to preserve those two registers.

#### Miscellaneous

1. In `gcd()`, why is the first instruction a nop?
2. I think that `main()` passed the arguments in the wrong order, but since `gcd()` is symmetrical, it doesn't matter.
3. You could merge the three return paths of `gcd()` into one, since they are all almost the same.

#### Rewrite of gcd

Here's how I would have written `gcd()`, given the restrictions:

1. It has to be recursive
2. No tail call optimizations are allowed
3. Cdecl calling conventon must be followed

The code:

```
gcd:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov     eax, [ebp+8]    ;var n
    mov     edx, [ebp+12]   ;var m

    cmp     eax, edx
    jg      GREATER
    je      FINISH

    sub     edx, eax ; LESS case
    jmp     RECURSE
GREATER:
    sub     eax, edx
RECURSE:
    push    eax
    push    edx
    call    gcd      ; args popped off by FINISH

FINISH:              ; return value must be in eax
    mov     esp, ebp ; restore sp (also pops off any args pushed)
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

#### Why use cdecl?

There was some discussion in the comments so I'm adding this section to clarify

I assumed you were using cdecl because your code appeared to follow that convention.  The main reason for using cdecl is so that your assembly code can call and be called by C code (or other code that follows cdecl).  That way, everybody agrees on where to place function arguments (e.g. on the stack instead of through registers), where the return value should go (e.g. eax), and which registers can be trashed by a function (e.g. eax ecx edx).

However, cdecl isn't the only calling convention for x86.  Furthermore, you don't even need any calling convention if you don't plan on linking with external code.  If you were trying to make your code as fast and small as possible, you would dispense with calling conventions and just do whatever was optimal.

For example, if you threw out calling convention, then you could change `gcd()` to not even use the stack.  You would pass arguments through registers instead.

#### Recursion a bad idea

Furthermore, using recursion for `gcd()` is a bad idea.  You could easily overflow your stack with `gcd(MAX_INT, 1)`.  Both the C and assembly versions of `gcd()` should be changed to use a loop instead of recursing.

However, I assumed that you were required to translate what you were given so I didn't emphasize this point before.

Comment: Thank you!, that was quite an improvement! I didn't know that those registers were volatile (I'm new at assembly). I am a little confused by what you mean as to merging the return paths.

Comment: @JaeJae55 What I mean is that the three different paths all ended with identical code "pop pop mov pop ret".  So instead of having 3 copies of that, just have the one copy and make the other 2 jump to the one copy.  If you look at my rewrite, there's only one exit path at FINISH with "mov pop ret", and the other two paths jump or fall through to it.

Comment: Oh! In the getintReturn, readNum and notEqual function. So You are saying to create a new function and  place a non conditional jmp for each of those functions in place of the code. which is the: pop edx; pop ecx; pop ebx; mov esp,ebp; pop ebp; and ret. My question is should the new function have the "ret" or would that effect the overall execution or rather "follow through" of the code.

Comment: 'those registers are volatile' if you decide that they are. There are conventions that are followed that make interfacing between (say) C and assembler possible. In order for the two to work together they must agree on how things work. But this is pure asm. JS1 uses cdecl in this example (presumably because you did), but there's no law that requires this. Dropping this requirement makes the code even smaller/faster. While using known conventions can make the code easier to read/maintain, one of the features (and also one of the dangers) of asm is you get to decide which, if any, to follow.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I'm not sure I follow, "Volatile if you decide they are" .

Comment: 'volatile' isn't some inherent attrib of those registers. Nor does the CPU treats them any differently.  It is a term that programmers use to describe the rules that a called function is going to follow. Saying they are 'volatile' just means "The function is allowed to change the value of these registers without being required to restore the original value."  This is one of the rules that makes up the cdecl abi.  However, cdecl is (as you might guess from the name) a c standard.  Asm *can* follow it, but doesn't have to. It's good to follow *a* standard, but you can make your own.

Comment: See also [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078) for the concepts of call-preserved (non-volatile) vs. call-clobbered (volatile) in calling conventions.  Also, x86 code golf tips [making up optimized calling conventions for specific functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020/30206) to minimize code-size.